# ICommand doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, icommand

I am starting with `MVVM` pattern and I have a problem with my button's command. I have a window which contains a `TextBox` for login and a custom `PasswordBox` with Password `DependencyProperty` for password (I know that any password should not be kept in memory, however it is only for fun, so do not be frustrated :) ) . There is also a button and I want it to be enabled if and only if the login and password are both not empty. However my command does not work properly. Here is the code:

**LoginWindow xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfMVVMApplication1.LoginWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfMVVMApplication1"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfMVVMApplication1.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Login" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Width="250" Height="150">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:LoginViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- here some styles for controls -->
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Login:"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Password:" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Login, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <local:MyPasswordBox Grid.Row="1" PasswordText="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding SaveUserCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

**My LoginViewModel class**

```
public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        SaveUserCommand = new Command(x => SaveUser(), x => { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Login) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password); });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ICommand SaveUserCommand { get; private set; }

    private string login;
    private string password;
    public string Login
    {
        get
        {
            return login;
        }
        set
        {
            login = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Login"));
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return password;
        }
        set
        {
            password = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Password"));
        }
    }

    public void SaveUser() { }
}
```

Also `MyPasswordBox` class may be useful:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfMVVMApplication1.MyPasswordBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfMVVMApplication1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <PasswordBox x:Name="password" PasswordChanged="password_PasswordChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MyPasswordBox : UserControl
{
    public MyPasswordBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PasswordText = "";
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PasswordText", typeof(string), typeof(MyPasswordBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(""));

    public string PasswordText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PasswordTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PasswordTextProperty, value); }
    }

    private void password_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordText = password.Password;
    }
}
```

I wrote some unit tests for that which checks the result of SaveUserCommand CanExecute method and they all passed. Furthermore, I run the debug in Visual Studio adding breakpoints in setters of `Login` and `Password` properties and they both are set properly.

I have run out of ideas what I could make wrong. Can anybody help me?

I feel that I don't notify the command about the changes properly, however I do not know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for WPF to pick up a change to whether a command can be executed, the command's `CanExecuteChanged` event needs to be fired.

You will need to fire this event when the login or the password changes.  You haven't shown the source of your class `Command`, but it will need to have a method that fires its `CanExecuteChanged` event.  Then, just call this method from the `Login` and `Password` property setters.