# C# WPF MVVM Light CanExecute not recognized

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

i am learning WPF and MVVM at the moment and having a little problem.

Im using MVVM Light and i want some Buttons to be dis/enabled after a validation, but its not using the functions.

ViewModelMain:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace EF_MVVM_Test
{
    public class ViewModelMain : ViewModelBase
    {
        public RelayCommand AddAuthorCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand DeleteAuthorCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand RefreshCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
        private LibraryContext db;

        private Author _SelectedAuthor;
        public Author SelectedAuthor
        {
            get { return _SelectedAuthor; }
            set { Set("SelectedAuthor", ref _SelectedAuthor, value); }
        }

        private Author _NewAuthor;
        public Author NewAuthor
        {
            get { return _NewAuthor; }
            set { Set("NewAuthor", ref _NewAuthor, value); }
        }

        public ViewModelMain()
        {
            db = new LibraryContext();
            db.Author.Load();
            Authors = db.Author.Local;

            AddAuthorCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteAddAuthorCommand, CanExecuteAddAuthorCommand);
            DeleteAuthorCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteDeleteAuthorCommand, CanExecuteDeleteAuthorCommand);
            RefreshCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteRefreshListCommand);
            SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteSaveCommand);

            NewAuthor = new Author();
        }

        private void ExecuteAddAuthorCommand()
        {
            db.Author.Add(_NewAuthor);
            NewAuthor = new Author();
        }
        private void ExecuteDeleteAuthorCommand()
        {
            db.Author.Remove(SelectedAuthor);
        }
        private void ExecuteRefreshListCommand()
        {
            db.Author.Load();
            Authors = db.Author.Local;
        }
        private void ExecuteSaveCommand()
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        private bool CanExecuteAddAuthorCommand()
        {
            return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewAuthor.Name) && NewAuthor.Birthday != null);
        }
        private bool CanExecuteDeleteAuthorCommand()
        {
            return SelectedAuthor != null;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Authors}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAuthor}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" Margin="5" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Birthday" Binding="{Binding Birthday}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Name" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox Height="25" Width="70" Margin="5" Text="{Binding NewAuthor.Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Geburtstag" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <DatePicker Height="25" Width="130" Margin="5" SelectedDate="{Binding NewAuthor.Birthday}"/>
            <Button Margin="5" Height="25" Width="80" Content="Hinzufügen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding AddAuthorCommand}"/>
            <Button Margin="5" Height="25" Width="80" Content="Löschen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding DeleteAuthorCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Width="120" Height="25" Content="Speichern" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
            <!--Button Width="120" Height="25" Content="Aktualisieren" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"/-->
        </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

any ideas why the buttons aren't using the canexecute functions?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the namespace you're using:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
```

Replace it with:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
```

Comment: You can't imagine the time you saved to me by this answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WPF's CommandManager calls `CanExecute` when it detects a UI changes? What constitutes a UI change? Adding and removing elements, *some* binding updates, visual state changes. Basically, whenever WPF feels like it. It is unreliable.

How can you skirt this? When you need to refresh a `RelayCommand`, call `RelayCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`. This method raises an event that notifies WPF that it should re-evaluate the status of the command.

Comment: [Using RelayCommands](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2009/09/using-relaycommands-in-silverlight-3-and-wpf/) seems to suggest using [CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx)

Comment: @Filburt That method will re-evaluate every `RelayCommand` and every `RoutedCommand`. Unnecessary for most scenarios if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the same problem as me a few days ago.

[ICommand doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284786/icommand-doesnt-work)

`ICommand.CanExecute` is not calling, because of course you don't say the button: "The ability of the button click may change when I insert something in the `TextBox`". So your button doesn't realize that he can be enable if textbox text changes. You must tell the button explicitly that it should check `ICommand.CanExecute` when the text changes, by raising the `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` event when textbox tex has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, unfortunately, you have to call the RaiseCanExecuteChanged method of the RelayCommand objects after assigning the SelectedAuthor and by intercepting the property change of the NewAuthor object.